# Finding minima using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I need to minimize the function $ f(A)= a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ on the set of matrices with determinant 1.

What I think is that we can take the determinant to be the constraint.

I am new to such type of problems a hint would do.

Thanks & regards

Comment: So we have a function $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$, and a constraint $ad-bc = 1$. What is stopping you?

Comment: Yup, the gradient of $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ is supposed to be a scalar multiple of the gradient of $ad-bc$. What's stopping you?

Comment: That's the easiest part. The gradients are parallel exactly at local extrema. One of the extrema must be the minimum. That's how you use that to find a minimum. What's stopping you?

Comment: Also how can i gaurantee the existence of minima? @Arthur

Comment: $f$ is the (square of the) distance from the origin to $A$ in $\Bbb R^4$. Your constraint is a closed set. That implies there is a minimum.

Comment: I think i get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, you just need to determine the critical points of the Lagrangian function and select the one that yields the minimum value. This approach works because:

1. the regularity of the objective function and the restriction, together with the fact that the Jacobian matrix of the restrictions has full rank over the feasible set, guarantees that every extrema will be a critical point of the Lagrangian.
2. The fact that the feasible set is closed, together with the interpretation of the objective function as the distance to the origin, guarantees that a minimum exists.

Comment: I am not sure what a lagrangian function is @PierreCarre :?

Comment: In this case, the Lagrangian function is given by
$$ L(a,b,c,d,\lambda) = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 - \lambda(ad-bc -1).$$
If you look it up you will easily find the definition.